# Inserting new row in excel by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet. In a column of the spreadsheet I have a list of codes (numbers).These codes (numbers) are sorted from highest to lowest values.(some of these codes has been repeated. For example I have three consecutive line with code 1001200).I want to insert new rows between each codes (in case of having repeated codes i just need one new row (for example i Just need one new row for 1001200 not 3 rows) .
I have written the following code but it does not work.

```
Sub addspace()
   Dim space_1(5000), Space_2(5000)

   For n = 1 To 5000
   Debug.Print space_1(n) = Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(1 + n, 1).Value
   Debug.Print Space_2(n) = Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(2 + n, 1).Value
   Next
   For n = 1 To 5000
   If space_1(n) <> Space_2(n) Then

   Range("space_1(n)").EntireRow.Insert

   End If
   Next
   End Sub
```

How can I fix it?  (From the code you can see that I am so beginner :)))

Cheers

Comment: Why macro if you can use remove duplicates and sort in any order as you require in excel?

Comment: Thanks for your response. These are not duplicated rows.  the values in Just one column is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

To insert one empty row between each unique value try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub addspace()
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("sheet3")
        For i = 5000 To 2 Step -1
            While .Range("A" & i - 1) = .Range("A" & i)
                i = i - 1
            Wend
            .Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

It starts from the end row and moves up, skipping duplicates

Answer (score 0):

The Range("space_1(n)") is invalid. Arg of range object should be a column name like "A1", you can use Range("A" & n).EntireRow.Insert in your code. But I recommend my code.

Please try,

```
Sub addspace()
Dim n As Integer

For n = 1 To 5000
    If Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(n, 1).Value <> Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(n + 1, 1).Value Then
        Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(n + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```